# Ionic 2 Refresher toggle ion-refresher on page load

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

**Overview:**

I make a network request to fill a list when my page loads in an Ionic 2 app. At this moment I am toggling a ion-spinner when the page initially loads.This is the refresher currently:

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">

  <ion-refresher-content
    pullingText="Pull to refresh..."
    refreshingSpinner="circles">
  </ion-refresher-content>

</ion-refresher>

<ion-spinner *ngIf="loading" color="light" name="circles"></ion-spinner>
```

My desired behavior would be to remove the ion-spinner component and just enable the ion-refresher when the page initially loads. I've seen a couple examples of this with Ionic V1, but I cant seem to translate it over to Angular 2.

**Question:**

Is there a way to trigger the ion-refresher and its spinner from my controller (*.ts), so I can remove the extra ion-spinner component from my template?

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @AndreasGassmann No i havent :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found a hack:

```
import { Content, Refresher } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  @ViewChild(Refresher) refresher: Refresher;
...
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.refresher._top = this.content.contentTop + 'px';
    this.refresher.state = 'ready';
    this.refresher._onEnd();
  }
```

This will show and trigger the refresher. It implicitly calls the registered refresh function.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try it out in a minute and let you know.

Comment: This seems very close. I've found that as of version 3.2, this works but doesn't show the spinner (though shows the space where it would be). `refresher._beginRefresh()` seems to have the same effect.

Comment: I found a method that works for me [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11393#issuecomment-316961038), which is very close to yours: `this.refresher._top = '50px'; this.refresher.state = 'refreshing'; this.refresher._beginRefresh();`

Answer (score 0):

For me you don't need ion-spinner

The doc say :

> The ion-spinner component provides a variety of animated SVG spinners. Spinners enables you to give users feedback that the app is actively processing/thinking/waiting/chillin’ out, or whatever you’d like it to indicate. **By default, the ion-refresher feature uses this spinner** component while it's the refresher is in the refreshing state

You have an example in the doc to do it

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/refresher/Refresher/

Edit : So use à method get data and call it in ionViewWillEnter.See comment at this post [How to dismiss Loader after data is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095474/how-to-dismiss-loader-after-data-is-ready)

Comment: The key word in my question is "initial". The refresher works as expected in all cases, I simply want to show the built in ion-spinner when the page loads and I make my initial http request.

Comment: So use à method get data and call it in ionViewWillEnter.See comment at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095474/how-to-dismiss-loader-after-data-is-ready

Comment: Still missing the point of my question. What you just said is exactly what I am doing. But I want to emit the refresh event and have the refresher component show the spinner on page load.